# FluentNHibernate - LazyLoad(Lazyness.NoProxy) doesn't exist

Tags: fluent-nhibernate, lazy-loading

i'm trying to use this feature of Fluent NHibernate:

https://github.com/jagregory/fluent-nhibernate/commit/92ad2d8c4ba8391c74fc8e32b36e71722b63dff0

But when i try to say:

```
HasMany(x => x.Details)
    .Inverse()
    .Cascade.All()
    .LazyLoad(Laziness.NoProxy);
```

There is no method called LazyLoad which accepts an argument.

My dll tells me i'm using version 1.1.0.685 of Fluent Nhibernate.  Please note that i am very new to NHibernate and would appreciate the help.  Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oops my bad.  You put it on the other end of the relationship (the many to one side).